# Vagrant 'EnableSendfile off' doesn't work

Tags: apache, static, vagrant, sendfile

I'm using Vagrant to set up a web server Apache2. So, I encountered a problem with cache from Apache:

I created a css file in my "Box Sync Folder Source". It's well updated in "Box Sync Folder Target" but when I refresh the browser no change is effective.

However I found "EnableSendfile Off" and "EnableMMAP Off" in my apache.conf ...

Anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm in a happy day : i understood why the EnableSendfile was down... In my Vagrant, i installed an apache module named SpeedPage, that keep cache from all static pages.
I desactivate this one and it runs well !