# Weird javascript fail with vagrant nfs enabled

Tags: javascript, vagrant, nfs, vagrant-plugin

I recieved an Unexpected token ILLEGAL error on javascript whith a function that i know that works. I fixed it by disabling the nfs plugin for vagrant after searching a lot, but i need that plugin for another part of the project to work. I looked into my vagrant's httpd.conf and EnableSendFile is set Off. I know that nfs (or something related) is causing the issue but cant find any other documentation nor tips to follow. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Could you please share some configuration so that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: i use a centos vagrant machine on a Windows 7 host. I need the nfs plugin because otherwise the session files of my project cannot be stored. I could post the Vagrantfile, but this configuration was working propperly until  a couple weeks ago when i reinstaled the vagrant machine. This reinstalation its the only change i made so i know is this what's causin the issue. I think this could be a permissions problem or some bad configuration.

Comment: just checked my permissions in vagrant and compared with a compannion whos working with the same configuration and we have the same permission on files, so i think this is not the issue, so it might be that the httpd.conf EnableSendFile off configuration is not being load... is there any way to check this?

Comment: just found this fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677553/vagrant-enablesendfile-off-doesnt-work , i dont have the SpeedPage module installed, but i learned the this might be caused by a module or some other config file. still dont know how to check my enablesendfile status.